# How to get Typescript to allow optional chaining to be undefined without warning message?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the example below, Typescript keeps warning that `obj?.[type]` implicitly has an any type. I want the callback to be able to be undefined or a function since I'm checking it afterwards. I want to keep the obj dynamic and not explicitly provide the type for it. How can I tell typescript to allow for this optional chaining statement to pass without a warning message?

```js
const obj = {
    row: {
        over: {
            page: () => { },
        },
    },
    col: {
        over: {
            page: () => { }
        }
    },
    el: {
        over: {
            page: () => { },
            row: () => { },
        }
    }
};

function myFn(type: "page" | "row" | "col" | "el") {
    const callback = obj?.[type]?.over?.[type];
    if (callback) {
        console.log("has callback");
    }
    console.log("no callback");
}
```

Typescript Playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBnmATiAO4BcGO+VcAbgKYHla7WsAOAhgOZ3kAUASlQA+DDAC+AGkqsJ0lniky8oADZNl1EPUYUFsvJx78hKUegmaq4zUv111eg9oYb9Bo7xiCRYuwaoiMm9TczkrfBt9KPEAbhwcADMAVzBgKABLcBgAWwBPADEwPig8ti8AIk8KmAAfGAqgmvqKtWaGhwqhZipQSFhgDlVVeA5gAGtUOCQAfgA6AG1S8oBdeZcCeaWyuhX4-QzE70Hh0YnuiJVwCBBVOjnVEC4+CoALDggYE5Gx8a796yaPo3O4PJ4vMAgL5DH4Tf44cRAA)

Comment: If you are getting a complaint about implicitly getting an `any` type, making it _explicit_ by typing `callback` as `any`. Or if you don't want that, come up with a better type for `obj`. The issue is not in the use of optional chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is not related with optional chaining. The `obj` doesn't contains `page` on first level, so it will cause this warning. you should define the type of `obj` like this:

```
const obj: Record<string, { over: Record<string, () => void> }> = {
    // ...
};
```

and it should works.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this comment at the beginning of the file to avoid type checking:

`// @ts-nocheck`

However you're also getting an error from a missing property there